# how to update custom field of a posts in a particular category

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a lot of posts under category 'tution', which has custom field called 'video'.
i need to update the 'video' value with same youtubeurl i.e all post would have the same value in the custom field 'video'. how should i proceed. Is their a query?

Answer (score 0):

if you can get access to your database through phpmyadmin
then you can use this sql statement to update your table rows with the video link

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='YOUTUBELINK' WHERE meta_key='video'
```

just remember to change the wp_postmeta if your database uses a prefix for your tables